# Coffee Script Replace

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, geektool

Found this new app called Ubersicht. It's seems to be a decent GeekTool desktop replacement on mac, the widgets use coffee script.

I found a great script : 
https://github.com/bgartenmann/uebersicht-only-this-widget

The script has no instructions. It references a text file called today.txt on the desktop. The idea is to put in your tasks for the day and they display in the widget.

```
 todayfile = '~/Desktop/today.txt'

 command: "cat #{today file}"

 refreshFrequency: 5000

 style: (a long list of css went here, did not think it was relevant)

 render: (output) -> 
 placeholder = "_____________"
 outputArray = output.split "*"
 goal = outputArray[0] || placeholder
 step1 = outputArray[1] || placeholder
 step2 = outputArray[2] || placeholder
 step3 = outputArray[3] || placeholder

    <p>If nothing else, today I am going to <span class="fillout">#{goal}</span>.<br />
     I am going to do this by <span class="fillout">#{step1}</span> then <span class="fillout">#{step2}</span> then <span class="fillout">#{step3}</span>.<br />
     <span class="motivation">If I do this and only this,<br /> today will be a <strong>good</strong> day.</span>"
```

I can't figure out how how to format the entries in the .txt file so that the entries end up in the right locations on the widget. I have tried multiple ways to reference step1 , one example being..

step1 = "this step"

Whenever I insert text, they always end up on the first line. How would I make it so the "tasks" entered in the .txt end up in their intended display location on the widget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for spreading a word about [Übersicht](http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/) and [this widget](https://github.com/bgartenmann/uebersicht-only-this-widget)! They're awesome!

The separator for items in the `~/Desktop/today.txt` file is an asterisk `*` character.

Here's is how my `~/Desktop/today.txt` looks like:

```
answer a beyonddynamic’s question on stackoverflow
*
reading widget’s source code
*
taking a screenshot
*
posting an answer on stackoverfow
```

Sentences could be written on one line if you prefer. New lines are optional.

[image: screenhot]

Comment: Thank Jev ! Yep , it's super cool, and maybe even easy to use, if your not a total code newb, aha. Really hope to see the community grow.